# summarizing a command

Tags: command-line

How can I summarize or condense these commands into a single command so that their functionality is preserved?

```
cp 1/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/001
cp 1/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/001
cp 1/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/001
cp 1/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/001
cp 1/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/001
cp 2/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/5/train/002
cp: target ‘../../5folds_all/augmented_images/5/train/002’ is not a directory
cp 2/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/002
cp 2/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/002
cp 2/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/002
cp 2/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/002
cp 2/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/002
cp 3/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/003
cp 3/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/003
cp 3/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/003
cp 3/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/003
cp 3/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/003
cp 4/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/004
cp: cannot stat ‘4/*.jpg’: No such file or directory
cp 5/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/005
cp 5/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/005
cp 5/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/005
cp 5/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/005
cp 5/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/005
cp 6/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/006
cp: cannot stat ‘6/*.jpg’: No such file or directory
cp 7/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/007
cp 7/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/007
cp 7/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/007
cp 7/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/007
cp 7/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/007
cp 8/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/008
cp 8/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/008
cp 8/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/008
cp 8/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/008
cp 8/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/008
cp 9/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/009
cp 9/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/009
cp 9/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/009
cp 9/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/009
cp 9/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/009
cp 10/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/010
cp: cannot stat ‘10/*.jpg’: No such file or directory
cp 11/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/011
cp: cannot stat ‘11/*.jpg’: No such file or directory
cp 12/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/012
cp 12/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/012
cp 12/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/012
cp 12/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/012
cp 12/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/012
cp 13/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/013
cp 13/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/013
cp 13/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/013
cp 13/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/013
cp 13/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/013
cp 14/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/014
cp 14/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/014
cp 14/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/014
cp 14/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/014
cp 14/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/014
cp 15/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/4/train/015
cp 15/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/3/train/015
cp 15/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/2/train/015
cp 15/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/1/train/015
cp 15/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/015
cp 16/*.jpg ../../5folds_all/augmented_images/0/train/016
cp: cannot stat ‘16/*.jpg’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What command? What do you mean by "summarize"?

Comment: I mean not writing the cp command for each folder specifically

Comment: @waltinator wait for my edit to roll in. if you read the copied code, you realized it's repeated `cp` commands for different folders. she would like a single `cp` command.

Comment: I don't understand the folder in between `augmented_images/1/train` (I mean the `/1/`).

Comment: @MonaJalal I think it's impossible as there is no pattern. like for example `images/1` doesn't increase at the same time as `cp 1/*.jpg` and `train/001`. only `cp 1/*.jpg` matches with `train/001` increases at the same time

Comment: ok was curious if it is possible or not. It's quite a lot. I will just save what I wrote and run the whole thing as a script.sh

Comment: @RoVo I am running 5 fold cross validation experiment and 1 represents the second fold

Comment: however 1/*.jpg represents all images in category 1

Comment: but sometimes you copy to folders 0-5, sometimes 0-4, sometimes only 0.

Comment: I updated the question. There is no 5 in my folds (my bad) only 0:4. Basically, when there is no image in my categories (1:16) after testing it and getting an error, I stopped copying it

Comment: Could you please edit the question title? I am not sure what to call this task!

Comment: @Mona There are some error messages in with the commands. Are those supposed to be there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested `for` loop, the outer one for the source index (`$i`), the inner one for the target index (`$n`):

```bsh
for i in {1..16}; do
  # Skip if no files found in $i/
  ls $i/*.jpg &> /dev/null || continue
  for n in {0..4}; do
      target="../../5folds_all/augmented_images/${n}/train/$(printf "%03d" $i)"
      # create target folder if not exists
      mkdir -p "$target"
      # copy to target folder
      cp $i/*.jpg "$target"
  done
done
```